# My try catch error message is not showing up

Tags: c#, xaml, if-statement, try-catch

I'm making a calculator, that calculates the resistance from voltage and current given to the program. When the program calculates the value, it's supposed to log the datetime, the used voltage, the used current and the value of the resistance to a text file in the given filepath. My problem is with the try / catch, if the program is given a wrong filepath, the error doesn't occur and the program simply doesn't log anything, as it doesn't have the correct file path.

So I want to make the program to show the messagebox error message and show the ex.Message, then you should be able to give the correct filepath to the program, and continue.

I have tried to place the try / catch outside the if / else, and on the inside, but the program does the same thing, it doesn't show the error message.

(If the code has typos they might be the result of me translating the names used to English from Finnish)

```
namespace Resistance calculator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txtLogPath.Text = "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\Log file.txt";
        }

        private void txtVoltage_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            txtVoltage.Clear();
        }

        private void txtCurrent_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            txtCurrent.Clear();
        }
        private void txtLogPath_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            txtLogPath.Clear();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(txtVoltage.Text, out double voltagevalue) &&
                double.TryParse(txtCurrent.Text, out double currentvalue))
            {
                double Result = voltagevalue / currentvalue;
                lblAnswer.Content = Result.ToString();

                try
                {
                    string logLine = DateTime.Now.ToString() + ", " + txtVoltage.Text + ", " + txtCurrent.Text + ", " + lblAnswer.Content;
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(txtLogPath.Text, logLine + "\n");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message + "Incorrect filepath!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error occured, please write numbers only.");
            }

            
        }


    }
    
}
```

Comment: What actually happens when you run his code?

Comment: The program runs and opens the MainWindow.xaml, I am able to input both values and when I press the btnCalculate, the lblAnswer shows me the correct answer. If I input an incorrect value to one of the textboxes (Voltage or Current) the later error messagebox appears. Also when I input correct values, the information shown are logged to the textfile mentioned in the filepath. Only when I have the incorrect filepath, the calculation happens as usual, but nothing is logged and the error message under the catch (Exception ex) doesn't show up.

Comment: Could you provide an example of "incorrect path"? And why you allow it be incorrect?

Comment: For example I put in a folder on my hard drive "D\\Dontexist" to test if the try parse works, as it should tell me that nothing can be stored within this file with the error message in 
catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message + "Incorrect filepath!");
                }
But it doesn't.

Comment: @UunoPurhaturo I have just tried a similar test, and the exception gets caught as you would expect. I cannot see why that would not heppen in your code. Are you certain that your code is not creating a log file in your invalid path?

Comment: @OldBoy I think it isn't, I've put in filepaths like "oijgnos" and "omfhnoenhpwe" so nonsense, but it still doesn't show me the errorbox when using those paths, so I'm out of ideas myself.
I did notice earlier that the D\\Dontexist did create a file with that name to my harddrive, so that experiment was a fluke.

Comment: @UunoPurhaturo Sorry, but I cannot think of any reason why this can happen.